# How to run an infinite-loop with an if-else statment while the system is on

Tags: 18.04, bash, scripts, system, c++

I'm working with robotics and we have had problems for run specific .exe while another (specific, too) .exe is runing. So, we want to kill all 'problematic' binaries before calling another one. For this purpose, I made an script with kill, but what I need is to make something like that:

```
While(The robot is on){
    if(A problematic binary was called)
      Call the script to kill all problematic binaries that are running now
      Run the called binary
}
```

I've already mapped the 'problematic' binaries, so the problem is just how to make this loop run all the time.

Thank You All!!

PS: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04

edit:
Sorry for my unclearness, I'll try to be more clear. It's something like that:

I have: A list of different binaries that we use, say: Walk , Run , Jump
Let's say, for example, that when a call ./Run and, after that, I call ./Walk without stopping the last binary, the system crashes. The same occurs when calling ./Walk before ./Run
But I have no problems when calling ./Jump

What I want is:

When calling ./Run -> Verify if ./Walk is running and kill it before running ./Run
When calling ./Walk -> Verify if ./Run is running and kill it before running ./Walk

`While(The robot is on){
    if(A binary of the list,Walk or Run, is called)
      Kill all the binaries of the problematic list
      Run the called binary
}`

Comment: I'm a little unsure if you need help implementing `while(robot_is_on)`? or you're looking for how to implement `while true`?

Comment: While (true) is sufficient, while the robot is off, the robot does nothing hahahaha
But I want this loop running automatically when the robot is turned on

Comment: I have asked to a friend and he said something about daemons

Comment: Almost that. The working script is sufficient if I call it in the start of each binary. In addition to it I need to detect the called binary so that a can call it again after killing all of the "blacklist"

Comment: I have no experience with robotics, but it seems like you're going about this the wrong way. I would rewrite the project so that `run`, `walk`, and `jump` are subcommands of a `robot` binary, which manages its state internally.

Comment: I agree - and I certainly don't see how an infinite loop helps - surely what you want to do is "wrap" each of the binaries in a script that kills the conflicting one(s) - once - before it runs?

Comment: You need a state machine. In `bash` it is not very easy to do, but could be done in Python or other languages. Also, you should write/rewrite the `run` , `walk` and `jump` command so that they cannot be called as standalone process, so you'd need them to be either a Python module or a C shared library.

Answer (score 1):

It is becoming more and more unclear what it is you actually want with the little information you have provided, there is no need to start a daemon if you just want a while true in a bash loop.

For here are two examples that should work just fine.

```
while :
do
  # loop infinitely
done
```

or

```
while true
do
   # loop infinitely
done
```

Comment: Sorry for my unclearness, I'll try to be more clear. It's something like that: 

I have: A list of different binaries that we use, say: Walk , Run , Jump
Let's say, for example, that when a call ./Run and, after that, I call ./Walk without stopping the last binary, the system crashes. The same occurs when calling ./Walk before ./Run
But I have no problems when calling ./Jump

What I want is: 
When calling ./Run -> Verify if ./Walk is running and kill it before running ./Run
When calling ./Walk -> Verify if ./Run is running and kill it before running ./Walk

Comment: I'll edit the question